# Can I force users to complete registration after facebook login, is it against TOS?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authorization

Question in simple, I have facebook app, thich is basically my site 1:1, but in facebook iframe.

I want to show a user a registration form after he logs in with facebook, containing the most common fields - username, email, password. After registration, I want to save facebook ID and create profile for this user.

Isn't it against facebook TOS to ask for username / password / email after user has entered site through facebook?

Thabks

Answer (score 0):

Why should it be against anything? They don't have to fill this form and proceed with registration on your website, so they're not really forced to do this.

In your FB app's settings, on **App Details** page there are textboxes for link to privacy policy and terms of service of your app. I think that you have to write in your own PP and TOS why you're asking for this data and what about privacy and all this stuff. And, of course, you should link to your app's PP and TOS on register page, or even "everywhere" in the footer so users will by able to check them easily.